# Post Body get's lost after accessing it in policy authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, policy

So I have a policy authorization in my asp.net core application. For one specific policy I need to access the body of a http post request. So I read the body like this:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AccessRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext authContext)
        {
            using (var stream = new StreamReader(authContext.HttpContext.Request.Body)
            {
                dynamic body = stream.ReadToEnd();
                // do more stuff
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

so far so good, all works well, BUT, in the controller itself the body then is null. I guess because the stream is already read? How can I *reset* the stream?

Swagger tells me

```
{
  "": [
    "A non-empty request body is required."
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to add `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: I tried that, but it says that operation is not supported (throws exception)

Comment: Before the using statement you try adding `authContext.HttpRequest.Request.EnableRewind();` as by default you cannot change the position of the stream that points to `Request.Body`